# prevent callbacks from being stopped when stopping parent function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, animation, callback, jquery-callback

It goes a little something like this:

```
$("example").hover(function(){
        ("example").stop().show(/*More Code*/, callback());
    }, function(){
        ("example").stop().hide(/*More Code*/, callback());
    }
)
```

So if the mouse were to leave the area before the first animation completed it would stop all animations, and skipping over the callbacks. Is there a way to use stop() and still execute the callback functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) that is timed to fire at the end of the animation instead of a callback.

```
$("example").hover(function(){
        $("example").stop().show(1000);
        setTimeout(function() { /* do something */ }, 1000);
    }, function(){
        $("example").stop().hide(1000);
        setTimeout(function() { /* do something */ }, 1000);
    }
);
```

Another option would be to use `.stop(true,true)` instead of just `.stop()`.

This clears the queue, sends the animation to the end, and fires the callback.

```
$("example").hover(function(){
        $("example").stop(true,true).show(1000);
    }, function(){
        $("example").stop(true,true).hide(1000);
    }
);
```